# Adding batch UIImage in viewcontroller occurs memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have 1 ViewController that have 90+ multiple questions. Also each question has ability add one or more image from UIImagePicker from camera. 30 or less questions does not have any problem but after 40 or 45th questions, program terminated without any specific error.

I have to keep all UIImage in memory until all questions has answered successfully and submit.

I am suspecting it's about memory issue.  I am assigning UIImage which is weak property :

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) UIImage *currentImage;
```

In implementation file :

```
self.currentImage =[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self fixOrientation]);

fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",formattedDateString];
```

Should i change properties of UIImage object as strong , instead of forcing memory to keep all images in memory until all questions has answered and submitted successfully ?

PS: UIImage property stands in cell prototype ViewController